# How to stop rmarkdown from generating the "attaching packages" when knitting to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I use rmarkdown for my intro to data science class. I recently lost a lot of points for formatting on a few homework assignments.

1. I would like to know if there is a way of getting rid of the "attaching" packages output when knitting to .pdf?

I have attached an image of the output and some formatting issues to this post.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either in code:

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)`

or in Rmarkdown format:

`#+ echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE`

Look it up in [Yihui's book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/), it's a good exercise.
You can also try to silence R itself:

```
debug.code <- FALSE # try TRUE to see the difference
options(warn = ifelse(debug.code, 1, -1), verbose = debug.code)
```

Comment: I totally forgot about Yihui's book! I appreciate the information and I will start going through it tonight!